# ChartJs 2.0 How do I obtain point information being clicked upon?

Tags: chart.js

How do you configure ChartJS version 2.0 to upon clicking on a point on a radar chart provide the data associated with that point i.e. label, data value, dataset name. I read on https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/releases that version 2.0 provides:

> New event hooks like onHover and onClick do the hard work for you. They pass  you the good stuff without even having to locate via event

Could someone please show me what I need to do I have read the documentation and tried attaching to the various click and onClick events which the different objects support but can not work out how to achieve getting the associated data.

Sample code (simplified) which I am using is:

```
<pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var config = {
      type: 'radar',
      data: {
      labels: ["Total IOPs","Total Num. Execs","Total Worker Time Seconds","Total  Physical Reads","Total Logical Writes","Total Logical Reads","Total Elapsed Time (s)","Longest Running Time (s)","Avg. IOPs per call","Avg. Elapsed Time (ms)","Avg. Num. Execs per Sproc","Avg IOPS per sproc"],
     datasets:
    [
     {
      label: "DB1",
      fillColor: "rgba(212, 212, 106, 0.2)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(212, 212, 106, 1)",
      pointColor: "rgba(212, 212, 106, 1)",
      pointStrokeColor: "#fff)",
      pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(212, 212, 106, 1)",
      data:[100,100,33.1715210355987,100,100,100,11.8161563835901,4.29405702507729,100,5.4590570719603,39.672945113066,100]
     },
     {
      label: "DB2",
      fillColor: "rgba(165, 198, 99, 0.2)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(165, 198, 99, 1)",
      pointColor: "rgba(165, 198, 99, 1)",
      pointStrokeColor: "#fff)",
      pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(165, 198, 99, 1)",
      data: [41.7446840202287,46.5744067420714,100,79.3727756793507,20.5131426518999,41.747519880759,100,100,89.6330850100954,100,100,16.5613115389214]
     }
     ]
     }
    };

     $(function () {
            var myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), config);
         //how do I attach to the onclick event which gives me the point info being clicked on in chartjs 2.0?
        });

</script>

<div class="radarChart">
     <canvas id="myChart" width="700" height="700"></canvas>
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to use the `getElementsAtEvent` method, like so

```
document.getElementById("myChart").onclick = function(evt){
    var activePoints = myRadar.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
    // use _datasetIndex and _index from each element of the activePoints array
};
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uwaszvk7/

Comment: Thank you, really most helpful.

Comment: I've been - like crazy - looking for an answer to this dilema. And `getElementsAtEvent` did the job.
chart.js documentation needs some serious update.

Comment: Nice answer! Same opinion as Alberto

Comment: This always returns the dataset 0, how can I obtain the real dataset clicked. Because if I have 4 datasets I always get the Dataset 0 index as the clicked one. Thanks

Comment: the "activePoints" var is actually the 2nd arg in the onclick = function(evt,activePoints) and is just the entire contents of your dataset.  It's unrelated to what you clicked.

Answer (score 9):

I have a graph with multiple data sets. Using the proposed `getElementsAtEvent(evt)` function, returns all data sets at a given x position but not only the single dataset index that I clicked on. So, there is no possibility to identify the individual data set.

To get only the single point clicked on:

```
const activePoint = chartObj.getElementAtEvent(event);
const datasetIndex = activePoint[0]._datasetIndex;
const itemIndex = activePoint[0]._index;
```

Notice the missing "s" in `getElementAtEvent()` compared to `getElementsAtEvent()`.

Comment: Sometimes an upvote isn't enough. Thanks for taking the time to post this. I spent like 3 hours trying to figure this out with the other answers, and I'm glad I finally scrolled to the bottom of this question.

Comment: Thank you! Beyond the accepted answer, lies the answer that answers the question. I appreciate you so much.

Comment: This is the correct solution to get the single point clicked on! It works for me! Vote it!

Answer (score 7):

In addition you can use `var activePoints = chartObj.getElementsAtXAxis(evt);` to get the nearest active element based just on the x-axis. (Super useful for when you have some really small values)

Answer (score 6):

Another way to achieve this in ChartJS 2.0 is to use the lastActive property of the radar chart.

```
var myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), config);
Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
Chart.defaults.global.hover.mode = 'single';
document.getElementById("myChart").onclick = function (evt) {
var activePoint = myRadar.lastActive[0];
if (activePoint !== undefined) {
        var datasetIndex = activePoint._datasetIndex;
                var index = activePoint._index;
                var datasetName = config.data.datasets[datasetIndex].label;
                var title = config.data.labels[index];
                var dataValue = config.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[index];
                alert("Dataset Name: [" + datasetName + "] title: [" + title + "] value: [" + dataValue + "]");
            }
        };
```

Comment: This is actually the way that worked for me. Althought I'm not using datasetName and no reference to datasetIndex (instead I use 0). But it works really good.

Answer (score 4):

> Calling `getElementsAtEvent(event)` on your Chart instance passing an
>   argument of an event, or jQuery event, will return the point elements
>   that are at that the same position of that event.

```
...
var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myRadar = new Chart(canvas, config);
canvas.onclick = function(evt) {

    // => activePoints is an array of points on the canvas that are at the same position as the click event.
    var activePoint = myRadar.getElementsAtEvent(evt)[0];

    if (activePoint !== undefined) {
        var dataset = myRadar.data.datasets[activePoint._datasetIndex];
        var title = myRadar.data.labels[activePoint._index];
        var oldValue = dataset.data[activePoint._index];
        var newValue = oldValue + 10;
        dataset.data[activePoint._index] = newValue;
    }

    // Calling update now animates element from oldValue to newValue.
    myRadar.update();

    console.log("Dataset: '"+ dataset.label + "' Element '" + title + "' Value updated from: " + oldValue + " to: " + newValue);
};
```