# How to have onclick/hover display associated value in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js, tooltip

I have a (regularly updating) ChartJS line chart as follows, working off of three types of data - `prices`, `dates`, and associated `more_info` - collected from a Django API:

```
<script>
    var myChart
    function refresh_graph() {
        {% block jquery %}
        var chart_endpoint = "{% url 'chart_data' current_id %}"
        var defaultData = []
        var labels = []
        var more_info = []
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: chart_endpoint,
            success: function(data){
                defaultData = data.prices
                labels = data.dates
                more_info = data.more_info
                if(myChart){
                    myChart.destroy();
                }
                var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
                myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets : [{
                            label: 'Price',
                            data: defaultData,
                            backgroundColor: [
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            ],
                            borderWidth: 2
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        elements: {
                            line: {
                                tension: 0 // disables bezier curves
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{
                                ticks: {
                                    suggestedMin: 0,
                                    suggestedMax: 1
                                }
                            }]
                        },
                        animation: {
                            duration: 0 // general animation time
                        },
                        hover: {
                            animationDuration: 0 // duration of animations when hovering an item
                        },
                        responsiveAnimationDuration: 0 // animation duration after a resize
                    }
                })
            }
        })
        setTimeout(refresh_graph, 5000);
        {% endblock %}
    }
    setTimeout(refresh_graph, 0);
</script>

<div>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="1000" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

**I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that, when the user clicks on or hovers over (I'd be happy with either) one of the data points in the graph (i.e., a `price` at a `date`), they'll see the associated `more_info`.**

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582122/chartjs-2-0-how-do-i-obtain-point-information-being-clicked-upon) using **`getElementById`**, but can't figure out how to extend that to a case like this, where I'm *not* looking to display a label (here: `date`) and a data point value (here: `price`), but rather a third value, i.e., `more_info`.

I'm also aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622356/chart-js-tooltiptemplate-not-working) way of using **custom tooltips**, but also can't figure out how to extend this from the case where I'm simply using `tooltipItem.xLabel` (`date`) and `tooltipItem.yLabel` (`price`), as opposed to a third, associated value.

Comment: Could you throw this on a codesandbox?

Comment: Thanks, @Mark. I've put a Codepen here (without the Ajax): https://codepen.io/kh_one/pen/OJJPBpJ. Let me know if you have any ideas!

Comment: It looks like you got it working, no?

Comment: @Mark - yes, that's right, got it to work using tooltips. Still have to work out how to format the tooltip (e.g., set its size) but the basic solution is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using tooltips (ignoring the Ajax from the OP):

```
var myChart
function refresh_graph() {
  var labels = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
  var defaultData = [0.1,0.5,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.3]
  var more_info = ["Monday info", "Tuesday info", "Wednesday info","Thursday info","Friday info","Saturday info","Sunday info"]

  if(myChart){
    myChart.destroy();
  }

  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: "Price",
        data: defaultData,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        borderWidth: 2,
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive : true,
      tooltips : {
        callbacks : {
          title : function() {
            return 'More information:';
          },
          afterLabel : function(tooltipItem, data) {
            return 'Information: ' + more_info[tooltipItem.index];
          },
        }
      },
      elements: {
        line: {
          tension: 0
        }
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            suggestedMin: 0,
            suggestedMax: 1
          }
        }]
      },
      animation: {
        duration: 0
      },
      hover: {
        animationDuration: 0
      },
      responsiveAnimationDuration: 0
    }
  })
  setTimeout(refresh_graph, 50000);
}
setTimeout(refresh_graph, 0);
```

Full codepen with custom tooltip here: https://codepen.io/kh_one/pen/OJJPBpJ.